# Dygraphs not working

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, dygraphs

Has anybody worked with dygraphs. I am new to it and I downloaded their files from the repository http://github.com/danvk/dygraphs. It has been mentioned to run the script generate-combined.sh I tried running it but it fails :-
sh generate-combined.sh
generate-combined.sh: line 32: perl: command not found
xargs: cat: terminated by signal 13

Note:- I am not good at Unix too.

Can someone help me get dygraphs working ?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the version at dygraphs.com/dygraph-combined.js if you can't build it locally.